# phone not visible to finder (on mac) suddenly

Tags: settings, usb

When I connect my phone to my mac via usb, I no longer see it in finder.  Nor does it automatically launch iphoto as it used to.

On the other hand, I can see it from sdk tools like ddms, and can access the files that way (with usb debugging turned on, of course).  I can also see other android devices just fine.

Is there some setting that got turned off somewhere?

MyTouch 4g, Froyo.

Comment: Could be recognized differently in USB debug mode, I suppose. You could try disabling that your settings then plugging it back in (not an answer: I have no idea if this is the reason).

Comment: Nope, doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling `Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB debugging` in conjunction with setting `Settings -> Applications -> USB settings` to **Mass storage**.  If that doesn't work, and enabling USB debugging doesn't work, then I would assume it's an OSX issue.  You could try reinstalling the official drivers, if there are any.

Comment: I can't find the "mass storage" setting.  I can get to Setting -> Connect to PC -> Default connection type -> Disk drive, though.  Doesn't help.

Comment: That's probably the same thing, so yea I'm guessing it's a PC-side issue.

Comment: Well rebooting the phone a second time seemed to fix it.  Rebooting the computer alone didn't.